# Minimal replica set config with backup

Tags: mongodb

Is a 3 node replica set w/ 1 hidden, voting member used as a backup source a viable configuration assuming read performance is acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default recommended setup for redundancy and backup on the documentation is 3 members.

It is perfectly acceptable for a startup set.

Answer (score 1):

Can't really give a better answer than: This would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, you have
1 primary, 2 secondaries, and a hidden node?

If so, don't do that - as the hidden node will still partake in elections, and you never want an even number of voting members.

I'd knock off one of the secondaries, so you're back to 3 nodes, or add in another secondary.

Comment: You would never want an even number of nodes on both sides of a partition, not nessecarily an even number by defacto.

Comment: You never want an even number of nodes by default, @Sammaye. There should only be an even number of nodes if and only if there is an issue (network partition, down node, etc)

Comment: If there are an even number of nodes on one side of the partition MongoDB can elect a primary, it is in the event of the CAP clause that MongoDB cannot elect a primary.

Comment: Yes, you can do a successful election with an even number of nodes - that's not what is in question here, @Sammaye. Having an even number on both sides of a network split ends up with a split brain - but this is not what OP has asked

Comment: He is asking if his setup is acceptable, the time it is not acceptable is if it cannot elect a primary, any other time and the replica set will function as desired. Your answer makes it out that you cannot do an election with an even number of nodes since you say...wait actually your answer contradicts itself now that I read it again. You say "you never want an even number of voting members." but then you also say "or add in another secondary." which is a contradiction to your first point

Comment: If you add in another secondary, you will have 5 voting nodes (hidden, primary, and 3 secondaries), as opposed to 4 (primary, 2 secondaries, hidden)

Comment: Ok so you mean add one ontop of the current configuration however "and you never want an even number of voting members." that line only makes sense if the replica is partitioned.

Comment: You can still get intra-datacenter partitioning - hence why you want an odd number of nodes.

Comment: That gets back to my original point, your answer assumes that even if there isn't a partition there should be an odd number of voters, that is untrue. You have pretty much confirmed my original comments

Comment: @Sammaye - No, I am correct. Always have an ODD number of replica set members. This includes hidden nodes.

Comment: So a primary can be elected with an even number of nodes on a single side of a partition (as you agree above), the reason for having (occording to the documentation) an odd number is because of paritition tolerance but you are still "correct" that you must have an odd number of voting nodes no matter what...

Comment: I should prolly say my last comment was more of a question actually also Note how I also said "voting" since you can have non-voting members in a replica set and the odd members thing relates specifically to votable/primariable members